# Set of units of polynomial ring $R[x_{1}, x_{2}]$ where $R$ consists of rationals of the form $\frac{n}{2^{m}}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, rational-numbers

Let $R = \mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1}{2} \right]$ be the ring of all rational numbers  of the form $\displaystyle \frac{n}{2^{m}}$. I need to describe the set of units of the polynomial ring $R[x_{1},x_{2}]$

I am assuming that polynomials in this ring look like $f = \frac{n_{3}}{2^{m_{3}}}x_{2}x_{1} +\frac{n_{2}}{2^{m_{2}}}x_{2} + \frac{n_{1}}{2^{m_{1}}}x_{1} + \frac{n_{0}}{2^{m_{0}}}$? Where $n_{i}$ and $m_{i}$ are integers?

Would I consider another polynomial $g = ax_{2}x_{1} + b x_{2} + cx_{1} + d$, multiply $f$ and $g$ together, and then figure out the general form I would need $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ to be in in order to get $fg=1$, or is there an easier and/or better way to approach this? If so, can you give me any guidance as to how to proceed?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In $R[x_1,x_2]$, the polynomials need not be just of degree $1$ in $x_1,x_2$ so your assumption about the general form for $f$ is incorrect. Secondly, have you found the units of $R$? Also you may want to first figure out if $R$ is an integral domain. That will help.

Comment: @AnuragA You're absolutely correct. I'll fix that. As for the units of $R$, they would be the set of all $\frac{n}{2^{m}}$ of the form $\frac{2^{m}}{n}$ (sorry for phrasing that so awkwardly), right?

Comment: The multiplicative inverse of $\frac{n}{2^m}$ is indeed $\frac{2^m}{n}$, which is generally a rational number but is *not* always an element of $R=\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}]$. When is it?

Comment: @arctictern When $n = \pm 1$?

Comment: There are more units than just $\pm1$. Mathei gives all the units in his answer.

Comment: @arctictern why did somebody downvote his answer? I upvoted it, so that must mean somebody else didn't like it. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Presumably because Mathei did the whole problem for you.

Comment: Polynomials in the ring $R[x,y]$ look like $\sum_{i,j} c_{ij}x^i y^j$, where the $c_{ij}$ are coefficients from $R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any integral domain $R$ we have $R[x]^{\times}=R^{\times}$, (mainly because $\mathrm{deg}(fg) = \mathrm{deg}(f)+\mathrm{deg}(g)$). If we apply this twice to $R[x_{1},x_{2}]$, we get that $R[x_{1},x_{2}]^{\times}=\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}]^{\times}$.

So it suffices to study the units of $R$. Consider $R$ as a subring of $\mathbb{Q}$ if $a = p  2^k \in R$ for $p,k \in \mathbb Z$, assuming $\mathrm{gcd}(p,2)=1$, $p\neq 0$, then $a \in R^\times \Leftrightarrow R \ni\frac{1}{a} = \frac{2^{-k}}{p}$, so $p = \pm1$, thus the units of $R$ are precisely the elements of the form $\pm 2^k$ for $k\in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: I am not familiar with the notation $^{\times}$. Does that mean units?